# How to use 3D Arrays in the game Hangman?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
public static String[] getWords(int cat, int diff) {
    String topic[][][] = new String[3][3][3];
    switch (cat) {
        case 0:
            topic[0][0][0] = "Paris";
            topic[0][0][1] = "London";
            topic[0][0][2] = "Sydney";
            diff = 0;
            topic[0][1][0] = "Toronto";
            topic[0][1][1] = "Florida";
            topic[0][1][2] = "Frankfurt";
            diff = 1;
            topic[0][2][0] = "Barcelona";
            topic[0][2][1] = "Vancouver";
            topic[0][2][2] = "Zimbabwe";
            diff = 2;
        case 1:
            topic[1][0][0] = "Halo";
            topic[1][0][1] = "Fifa";
            topic[1][0][2] = "GTA";
            diff = 0;
            topic[1][1][0] = "Skyrim";
            topic[1][1][1] = "HITMAN";
            topic[1][1][2] = "Batman";
            diff = 1;
            topic[1][2][0] = "Minecraft";
            topic[1][2][1] = "Zombieville";
            topic[1][2][2] = "BoderLands";
            diff = 2;
        case 2:
            topic[2][0][0] = "Acura";
            topic[2][0][1] = "Audi";
            topic[2][0][2] = "Bmw";
            diff = 0;
            topic[2][1][0] = "Bentley";
            topic[2][1][1] = "Buggati";
            topic[2][1][2] = "Honda";
            diff = 1;
            topic[2][2][0] = "Lamborghini";
            topic[2][2][1] = "Rolls-Royce";
            topic[2][2][2] = "Mercedes";
            diff = 2;
    }
    return topic[cat][diff];
}
```

This is going to be 3d arrays and have 3 option, which includes the level diffivculty and the category, how can i call it in and use it as if the person choose this... it will go through the array and pick this i am going to put this in a method and call it in the main method

Comment: thee movies is suppose to be places

Comment: also your edit is not showing up

Comment: how do u make it show and it is showing for me

Comment: You need to wait for some one to approve your edit

Comment: check my other question from my profile, someone edit my code

Comment: i put the whole code there

Answer (score 2):

so your asking how to use your array? the simplest way would be to create a method that returns the value stored at the proper category and difficultie

I.E.

```
public String[] getWords(int cat, int diff)
{
 return topic[cat][diff];
 }
```

you could call the method and then select a word for the player to guess at from the returned array.

UPDATE:

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that your pretty new at programming and that you don't understand how to use methods yet. [Some light reading might help with that.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) you define the method out side of your main method and Call to retrieve words for a given player. You pass in two ints, that are then used to designate the position in the array that you would like to access.

Comment: basically do yuo mean use this method and between the return and the method put my array list how it is or should i change it

Comment: why did you put int, isn't it String